# Calculating greatest common divisor

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

I have written the following function to calculate GCD of floating point numbers, but when I run this for the input (111.6, 46.5), the calculation of fmod(a,b) in the funciton starts giving the wrong result after 2 recursive calls. I am unable to find the error here. Can anyone find what is going wrong here?

```
float gcd(float a, float b){
if (a>b) {
    if(b==0){
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return gcd(b, fmod(a,b));
    }
}
else {
    if (a==0) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return gcd(fmod(b,a), a);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: What do you mean by gcd of floating point numbers? I don't think this algorithm can work for anything but integers. And even if it works for rational numbers, I don't think it can work for floats.

Comment: what value were you expecting for gcd(111.6,46.5)?

Comment: @zch: Of course the algorithm works for rational numbers and floats. Euclid originally wrote it for real numbers, in the form of line segments. (*Elements*, Book VII, circa 300 BCE: Propositions 1 and 2.)

Comment: @zch floats are precisely rational numbers, extended with infinity and NaN, even if they cannot represent any rational numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the way that floating-point values are represented, the source text “111.6” is converted to 111.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375, and the source text “46.5” is converted to 46.5. Then your `gcd` function returns 7.62939453125e-06. That is the correct GCD of the two input values.

Note that the first value is 14627635/131072. All floating-point numbers are some integer (within a certain range) multiplied or divided by a power of two. It is impossible to represent 111.6 exactly with binary floating-point. Since you cannot represent 111.6 exactly, you cannot do exact arithmetic with it. Floating-point is largely designed for approximate arithmetic. Doing exact arithmetic requires a great deal of care.

---

> What does it mean to talk about the GCD of real numbers (as opposed to integers)?

The GCD of *a* and *b* is the largest number *c* such that *a*/*c* and *b*/*c* are integers.

Comment: What does it mean to talk about the GCD of real numbers? (as opposed to integers)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The GCD of a and b is the largest number c such that a/c and b/c are integers.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: So? Would you also lodge a complaint about division on the integers since, in general, the quotient of two integers does not exist? (E.g., 1/0.) I feel as comfortable talking about the GCDs of real numbers as I do the quotients of integers.

Comment: But that's clearly a degenerate case.  In the case of the GCD of reals, almost all (in the mathematical sense) pairs don't have a result.

Comment: @Oli: I do not understand why you think it is not relevant or why you have a complaint. We define the quotient of two numbers a and b as the number c such that a = b*c. Sometimes no such c exists, in which case there is no quotient. Similarly, the GCD of two numbers and and b is the largest number c such that a/c and b/c are integers. Sometimes no such c exists, in which case there is no GCD. I have not asserted that the GCD always exists. So what troubles you?

Comment: Although I suppose in the case of a floating-point implementation, `a` and `b` must be rational, and so the GCD does exist...

Comment: No such quotient exists in general in the integers, it's true.  But what concerns me is that the GCD algorithm for the case of reals is almost entirely useless for any practical purpose.

Comment: Don't the straight equality checks also ring a few bells? `a == 0` sounds like a recipe for disaster to me...

Comment: @thkala: The notion that you cannot test for equality in floating point is a myth. A more correct statement is that you cannot accurately calculate a function of inaccurate inputs. Equality is just the most notorious example (“Here is something that is close to a and something that is close to b. Are a and b equal?”), but other functions have problems too (“Here is something close to a. It may be greater than 1, even though a is not. What is the arcsine of a?”). In this case, all of the math inside `gcd` is exact, so there is no inaccuracy and no problem with `==`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: So `fmod` is exact in the general case? I was not aware of that...

Comment: @thkala: It's probably "exact" in the sense of returning the closest possible answer to the true result.

Comment: @thkala: Yes, `fmod` is exact, unless it has a bug, of course. The mathematical result of `fmod` always has a most significant bit (MSB) that is no higher than the MSB of the smaller of its inputs and a least significant bit (LSB) no lower than the LSB of the smaller of its inputs, so the exact result always fits within the floating-point type. Since the exact result is representable, it should be returned.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: No, the term for that is “correctly rounded”. `fmod` is exact. In order of decreasing strictness, floating-point operations can be exact (exact mathematical value, zero error), correctly rounded (nearest representable value, following rounding rules), faithfully rounded (one of the nearest two values), or worse.

Answer (score 0):

```
float gcd(float a, float b){
    printf("a=%f b=%f\n",a,b);
if (a>b) {
    if(b==0){
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return gcd(b, fmod(a,b));
    }
}
else {
    if (a==0) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return gcd(fmod(b,a), a);
    }
}
}
main(){
    printf("%f\ndddeellliiimmiitteerr\n",gcd(1116,465));
    printf("%f\n",gcd(111.6,46.5));
}
```

so as u can see float not so accurate . 
you can try double (but it too :) ) or ... read about how float stored